# French artist, guitar + strong voice, does exist?

Tags: identify-this-genre, guitar

I don't know if it is right place to ask, nevertheless I will give it a try.

I am looking for a specific type of French music - guitar (no other instruments) and strong voice, something like Wladimir Wysocki (russian artist):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyEdfuUVLtY
or Jacek Kaczmarski (polish artist): (a little bit of piano, but not really overwhelming)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERBV09Rap2k

I will be really gratefull for any hints, links.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There quite a few french "balladeurs", as they are sometimes called, that may fit your description. Can you provide some more information? (new/old guy, aproximate decade most active, etc.)

Comment: I really enjoy this type of music, whether he is new or old nor the most active decade makes no difference for me. It would be good if in his singing was contained some kind of "message", e.g. J. Kaczmarski was singing about polish political situation (through images, not directly), he was also often inspired by literature, art. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the quintessential French *balladeur* accompanying himself (mostly) with a classical guitar, I suggest [Georges Brassens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QiXvQ98aJw). He has a deep baritone voice, but not rough as the Russian example provided by the OP. His lyrics are extremely poetical, in a vein more lyrical than political, but some social concerns with an anarchist influence are also present.

There are many many French singers cultivating a somewhat similar type of voice, within the aesthetics and repertoire of the "[*Chanson française*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanson_fran%C3%A7aise)". Some of the most well known are for example [Yves Montand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yves_Montand), Serge Regianni, [Gilbert Bécaud](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_B%C3%A9caud) or [Serge Gainsbourg](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serge_Gainsbourg) (of "[Je T'Aime Moi Non Plus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlpDf6XX_j0)" fame).

A somewhat more politicized figure is Georges Moustaki, who often sang with only his guitar. But his voice is a velvety tenor, far from the rough voice examples of the OP.

Finally, even leaving many names without mention, it would be impossible in this context not to mention [Jacques Brel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPJAydTtoDw), whose theatrical (sometimes histrionic) interpretations are perhaps without parallel.

Answer (score 2):

There is **French blues** that comes from North America and some from the Metropolitan France/Belgium.  Some of it is with only a guitar and harmonica and sometimes more robust.  Determined mostly by recording.

[Bernard Adamus - Brun (le couleur de l'amour)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B61pW6LXAvw)

[Mononc Serge - Charlie Hebdo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8B7YZMs_3g)

[Lisa Leblanc - Aujourd'hui, ma vie c'est la marde](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kF7DW_mZatA)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not really what I am looking for - blues is a music to chill out, while I would like to find something more energizing